# Get stuck on eternal loop

Tags: javascript, php, apache, docker

I have:

- Last Docker and docker-compose
- [php:5.6-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)

This simple code (sse.php):

```
<?php
// Set necessary headers
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');


$lastId = 0;
while (true) {
    $lastId++;
    sendMessage($lastId, rand(1, 99));

    sleep(1);
}

// Function to send data in format "ticket:price".
function sendMessage($id, $data)
{
    echo "id: $id\n";
    echo "data: $data\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

If I'll run this in console:

```
curl http://localhost/sse.php
```

I'll see what I want to see (example):

```
id: 1
data: 41

id: 2
data: 12

id: 3
data: 7

id: 4
data: 10
```

But if I try to open this link http://localhost/index.php, I can't do it. Seems like it tries to connect but without any success:

[image: Eternal loading]

And when I reset curl (`Ctrl+C`), after few moments page opens

The same situation with this JS code in browser:

```
var eventSource = new EventSource('/sse.php');
eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("Пришло сообщение: " + e.data);
};
```

It works:

[image: Все работает замечательно]

But I cant open another pages.

After `eventSource.close()` all works fine.

How can I fix this issue? What I do wrong? Help me please `// Sorry for my bad Enlish`

**PS:**

I tried to add this lines  from internet into apache config, nothing was changed:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit              250
    StartServers              10
    MinSpareThreads           75
    MaxSpareThreads          250
    ThreadLimit               64
    ThreadsPerChild           32
    MaxRequestWorkers       8000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to connect to server using another device.

- I run this command on PC `curl http://localhost/sse.php` which causes problems in browser.
- I open `http://192.168.0.1/` in browser on mobile and it opens without any problems

I think apache or docker limits connections per client, but cant find any info in web...

**UPDATE 2**
More information:

- [/etc/apache2/apache2.conf](https://pastebin.com/b7qBbarS)
- [/etc/apache2/conf-available/site-configuration.conf](https://pastebin.com/uc8uG7m6)
- [/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf](https://pastebin.com/6HFq25K3)

Comment: That picture's really useful...

Comment: Your loop never ends so PHP server can't send anything to your browser. PHP doesn't output anything untik the full code has been run. So in your case nothing is output because you don't let the code finnish.

Comment: @Federico the picture shows a browser that is waiting for response from server. In my opinion it's useful. It shows the server is not done with the code

Comment: So - what are you trying achieve with this page?

Comment: @Andreas you are not attentive. Server sends data to browser or console (curl). But **another pages** do not open when I connect to the server using Server Side Events

Comment: @NigelRen I try to create real time application using Server Side Events with PHP.

Comment: Added some extra useful info

Comment: I think apache somehow limits connections per client. But I can't figure out how to increase it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found the solution](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758078/4065)! If you run into such a problem, try to disable xDebug and close the session `session_write_close()`.
PHP Locks session write for one connection and it's causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [flush](http://php.net/flush), the output needs to be longer than just some bytes to be really flushed to the browser. Try adding something like `echo strpad(' ', 2048);` before calling `flush()`

Comment: I think problem in docker or apache. Not in PHP code. You can Google server side events

Comment: Trying out my solution is a no brainer - if it doesn't solve the problem, it's just five wasted minutes. But if you don't want to give it a chance, you're welcome :)

Comment: Okay. But what do you mean by „server side events“?

Comment: this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events